# Get updated data from network with pagination in android

Tags: android

I'm using pagination to get data from network as the only datasource. In the PagedListAdapter I have a button which on click will update the data in the network  now I need to get the updated data and change the view for that item. How do I do that?. Is there a way to achieve this without using db?...

lets say I have a Model named Post and it has a field named isSaved. so what I'm doing rt now is when I click the save button in the PagedListAdapter view then I'm calling an api to update that field ..so now I want to get the updated value for that particular post item and change the button's text as saved....since i'm using adapter.submit(listOfPost), the list is the same so DiffUtil itemCallback isn't being called...What should I do??

Comment: in your api are you passing page number parameter?

Comment: Yes, I am passing page_no and page_size as parameters

Answer (score 0):

Suppose when you pass page 1 then take example its returning you 30 items. So all you have to check here is whether recyclerview can scroll vertically or not. If not then increase the page number and call api method again.

And to check whether recyclerView have more item to scroll below method will help you.

```
   mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

            if(!mRecyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)){
                // search the next page
                searchNextPage();
            }
        }
    });
```

For more details this link will be helpful for you: https://github.com/mitchtabian/RestApiMVVM

Comment: lets say I have a Model named Post and it has a field named isSaved. so what I'm doing rt now is when I click the save button in the PagedListAdapter view then I'm calling an api to update that field ..so now I want to get the updated value for that particular post item and change the button's text as saved....since i'm using adapter.submit(listOfPost), the list is the same so DiffUtil itemCallback isn't being called...What should I do??

Comment: In that case you should call listing api again in success response of update api.

Comment: yeah that's what I did but it updates the whole list and not the particular one that I'm trying to get so if I'm at position 10 the whole list updates and scrolls to the top

Comment: You can use notifyItemchanged() and pass the position  of item which you are updating  100% it will work.